# C# LINQ query a List<Dicitonary<string, object>>

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

I have a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` where `Dictionary<string, object>` is like:

I have to use `Dictionary<string, object>` as I am retrieving different objects from an API and specifying each object is not feasible.

```
{
    [id, 12345],
    [action, SUBMIT],
    [comment, blah blah]
    ...
},
{
    [id, 98765],
    [action, DECLINE],
    [comment, yak yak]
    ...
}
```

'id' is always an integer.

How can use LINQ to query the max id from the List?  In this case returning id=98765.

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself? Any attempts?

Comment: I have used LINQ a few times but am not familiar with how to query into the Dictionary items and cannot find anything on Google about how to do this.

Comment: I would strongly suggest turning those dictionaries into actual objects, with properties instead of keys and values for those properties instead of values from a key-pair.  If you really *must* do this, then fine, but if you can possibly avoid it (and you usually can), you really should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break the problem down into component parts:

1. I need to extract the ID entry from each dictionary into a set.
2. I need to convert the value into an integer.
3. I need to get the max value of that set.

How do we access the value of a dictionary entry by its key? `myDictionary["key"]`. This is brittle because it assumes the dictionary will always have an entry with that key. If it doesn't, it will throw an exception.

How do we use LINQ to produce a new sequence of objects from an existing sequence? `Select()`. Describe the output object for each object in the source.

We get an int from a string by using `int.Parse`. This is brittle and usually a no-no, because if that string value is ever not perfectly an integer, it will throw an exception. But for simplicity let's say we can assume all strings will always be integers, like you said.

The last bit is the easiest - Max() works on any sequence of comparable items:

```
var maxId = theList.Select(dict => int.Parse(dict["id"].ToString())).Max();
```

Now a safer version would make sure to do two things:

1. Check to see if the dictionary actually *has* an "id" entry, and if not, decide how to deal with that.
2. Check to see if the entry value actually *can* be converted to an integer, and if not, decide how to deal with that.

Here's one way which just skips entries that don't meet the two requirements. If there are no entries that pass, `DefaultIfEmpty(-1)` produces a sequence with a single entry, -1.

```
int tryParse;
var onlyEntriesWithIdThatAreIntegers = theList.Where(
    dict => dict.ContainsKey("id")
        && dict["id"] != null
        && int.TryParse(dict["id"].ToString(), out tryParse))
    .DefaultIfEmpty(-1);

var max = onlyEntriesWithIdThatAreIntegers.Select(
    dict => int.Parse(dict["id"].ToString())).Max();
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.  I only choose this one as the correct answer as it broke down the example, explaining the various parts of the query (very helpful!).  BTW, I had to use dict["id"].ToString() since it is an object (in case someone else encounters this answer).

Comment: @BrianKE glad you found it helpful. If you want to accept this answer, click the check-mark to the left, under the voting buttons.

Comment: I tried to accept but have to wait 10 minutes apparently.  You will just have to wait, that is your punishment for being such a fast and good teacher! :)

Comment: BTW, how do I add the '@Rex M' to the comment (like you did with @BrianKE) and what does that do?

Comment: @BrianKE type '@' and the first few letters of the name and it should pop up with an auto-complete. It has to be the first character in the comment though.

The main thing it does is make sure you get a site-wide alert that a comment is addressed to you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me.  Could it have to do with my rep or something else?  When I typed '@Rex M' at the beginning of the message, it is deleted when I post the comment. And it did not auto-complete or offer any suggestion.

Comment: @BrianKE dunno. It doesn't look like it's rep-constrained. Here's the info on @-user: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: @BrianKE updated with a more fault-tolerant example.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you looking for:

```
    var result = youList.Select(p=>int.Parse(p["id"])).Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I agree with Grant. You should use an object instead of a dictionary to represent your objects.

```
var values = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
... populate the list ...

int maxIdValue = values.Where(v => v.Keys.Contains("id")).Select(v => (int) v["id"]).Max();
```

You SHOULD do a check to make sure the dictionary contains the ID property, else you will get an exception. Also, you should really use case-insensitive dictionaries for what you are doing. The comparisons are faster, and you have less to wory about ("id, Id, ID") being all the same for your purposes. Also, Int.Parse is SLOW. If the object is an Int, just cast it, bo need to turn it into a string and then parse it to convert it back to the type it already is! But, if you MUST use int.Parse, because the values are not guaranteed to be an int, then USE TryParse. Otherwise, once again, un-handled exceptions

## Edit:

If you want to use tryParse, here is an example:

```
        var intValues = values.Where(v => v.Keys.Contains("id")).Select(v =>
        {
            int val;
            if (int.TryParse(v["id"].ToString(), out val))
            {
                return val;
            }
            return int.MinValue;
        }).Where(v => v > int.MinValue);

        int? maxIdValue = null;
        if (intValues.Any())
            maxIdValue = intValues.Max();
```

Comment: I agree with using TryParse but cannot figure out how to apply it in this situation.  TryParse returns a bool and I am not sure how to set the out value such that the LINQ query can access it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you, did not realize you could do the {} callout.

Comment: I modified it again, to ensure that if there are no parse-able ints, you don't get a sequence contains no elements error.